# java.lang.NullPointerException occured while running the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi all I am writing a simple registration form to register and for that servlet.
I have included all the entries in web.xml. but i dont know why I am getting the "java.lang.NullPointerException". every thing looks fine to me but I am not able to figure out the loophole. please help me out with this.

**index.jsp**

```
<form action="InsertRecord" method="post">
    <fieldset> 
     <legend>
        <font face="Courier New" size="+1" 
                color="red">
                Student Registration
        </font>
    </legend> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Student Name &nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Enrollment Number &nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="enrolmentNo"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Program Name &nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="program"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Gender &nbsp;&nbsp; : </td>
            <td><select Name="gender">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>      
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address &nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20"></textarea> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Registration"></td>
     </table>
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>student</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
         </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InsertRecord</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.varun.InsertRecord</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InsertRecord</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/InsertRecord</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**InsertRecord.java** This is servlet

```
   package com.varun;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    public class InsertRecord extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String en=request.getParameter("enrolmentNo");
            String program=request.getParameter("program");
            String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
            String address=request.getParameter("address");

            int id=0;
            int enrol=0;

            if(name.equals("")||en.equals("")||program.equals("")
                    ||gender.equals("")||address.equals(""))
            {
                out.println("Please insert the valid data");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("good job");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/sucess.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Include the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: When troubleshooting Exceptions please include the full stack trace in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the String `address` is null.

```
String address=request.getParameter("address");
```

because your textarea has no name:

```
<td><textarea rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
```

change it to

```
<td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name ="address"></textarea>
```

and the exception should gone away.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have any parameter with name `address` and you are fetching in request `request.getParameter("address");` giving you a null value.

Add `name` attribute in textarea and it will work

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="address"></textarea>
```

Comment: That is not correct. The NullPointerExcpetion will be at `address.equals(""))`. Not in `request.getParameter("address")`

Comment: @Jens sorry but I dont aggree the nullpointer will be on `getParameter`

Comment: @singhakash The getParameter call will return a null and not throw an Exception.  Only when you try to *use* the value will you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @singhakash I f you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))  you can see that it wil return null if the parameter is not in the request: `Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

The below line of code can be the reason of exception :

```
    String address=request.getParameter("address");
```

as you have not defined any html field with the attribute name **address**.

```
        <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
```

include **name="address"** attribute in above textarea. 
This may solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Correct your .jsp code :

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="20" name ="address"></textarea>
```